# Panel data in R plm package

Tags: r, panel, plm

I have a problem with the estimation of a panel data model in R. 
I want to estimate the effect of a change in the Real GDP and the relative price level in the respective country on the contribution of the tourism sector.

If I use the command

```
Y <- cbind(ln_Differences_Contribution)
X <- cbind(ln_price_differences, Differences_ln_gdp)
```

and then

```
fixed <- plm(Y~X, data=pdata, model = "within")
```

I do not have an effect for the different years.

Is there anyway I can add a time variable?

Comment: The usage of the formula interface is a bit weird. Why do you create Y and X and then specify `pdata` as the source of X and Y when they are self contained objects? Please make your example reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control for the effect of the time period ("years"), you can use the `effect` argument to additionally specify time effects in a two-way within model:

`plm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = pdata, model = "within", effect = "twoways")`

Another way would be to explicitly include the time variable in the formula as a factor and specifying a one-way individual model as in your question, assuming your time variable is called `year`:

`plm(y ~ x1 + x2 + factor(year), data = pdata, model = "within")`

The output would be a bit "polluted" by the explicit estimates for the years (usually, one is not interested in those).